# Computing partial derivatives of $f(a,b)= \int_{0}^{1}(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})^{2}dx$ using chain rule.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f(a,b)= \int_{0}^{1}(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})^{2}dx$. I want to compute $\frac{\partial{f(a,b)}}{\partial{a}}$ and $\frac{\partial{f}(a,b)}{\partial{b}}$. I was told in the text that $$\frac{\partial{f}(a,b)}{\partial{a}}=2. \int_{0}^{1}(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^{2}})dx x$$ and $$\frac{\partial{f}(a,b)}{\partial{b}}=2. \int_{0}^{1}(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^{2}})dx$$ because the Chain rule but I cannot justify this. I was thinking this holds because if $f(a,b)=F(H(a))$ where $$F(t)=\int_{0}^{1}(t+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})^{2}dx$$ and $H(a)=ax$, then $\frac{\partial{f(a,b)}}{\partial{a}}=F'(H(a))H'(a)$ but there are counterexamples where $f(a,b) \neq F(H(a)$. Can anyone help me fill the gaps about how these partial derivatives were obtained?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is because the derivative with respect to $a$ of $(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2}$) is $x$. Best keep the $x$ inside the integrand before the $dx$.

$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_0^1 (ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})^2 dx  $

$= \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial a}(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})^2dx = \int_0^1 2(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})' dx = \int_0^1 2(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})x  dx $

Comment: Why the two appears? Also what is the role of the integral? @GeorgeDewhirst

Comment: $2$ is the derivative of $x^2$, and our expression is $g(a)^2$ so the derivative wrt $a$ of this is $2g(a)g'(a)$

Comment: How is explicitily $g(a)$ expressed $g(a)=(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})$ or   $g(a)= \int_{0}^{1} (ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})$?

Comment: The first one. We are differentiating $\int_0^1 g(a,x)^2 dx$, we are allowed to take the partial derivative inside of the integral.

Comment: So $g(a,x)^{2}=(ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})$?? and  partial derivative of $f(a,b)$ as I defined is the same of diferentiating $\int_{0}^{1}g(a,x)^{2}$??? And differentiating this last one is $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial{g(a,x)^{2}}}{\partial {a}} $ ????

Comment: Yes so long as $g(a,x)^2 = (ax+b+\frac{1}{1+x^2})^2$

Comment: How can I justify the fact differentiating an integral can be taking the partial derivative inside the integral? Also, if it is not problem at all could you calculate one of these partial derivative since still there is some steps im still not sure at all at this new topic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule for differentiating the integral. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were really helpful understanding this concept of partial derivatives of an integral!

Comment: Haha no worries any time